# How many API calls does dataloader use

Tags: data-loader

We are using dataloader to delete several hundred thousand records. As stated in Salesforce knowledge, it should be 1 API call per batch. However, our BA told me that she watched the API usage went up very quickly when using dataloader.

Theoretically, I know see that should be an issue as it is stated in Salesforce knowledge. And it could probably be a mere coincidence that other processes are also running simultaneously. However, I just want to double confirm it is the case. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

Comment: May not be your issue but I once forgot I had the batch size set to 1 and brought a production org to its knees when the API limit was quickly exceeded from trying to update 300k records. So double check batch size is set to a high value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best option could be to check the [Data Loader Log File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_troubleshooting.htm). It apparently tracks:

> the operations and network connections made by Data Loader

So it would give you a very direct indication of the API calls being made.

---

Conversely, you could directly [monitor your Salesforce API usage](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/06/monitoring-your-salesforce-api-usage.html).

If you can access it (Paid Feature), the [Event Monitoring API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_event_log_files.htm) will tell you exactly which API calls have been made by the Data Loader. This will be particularly easy if you have a User that is only being used by the Data Loader.

Also, check that Data Loader is configured to use the Bulk API - [Data Loader Behavior with Bulk API Enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/loader_using_bulk_api.htm)

---

Once you know you are using the [Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart_requests_intro.htm), you will definitely need more that one API call to get things going.

Calls would include:

1. Creating the Job
2. Adding Batches to the Job
3. Closing the Job (to start processing the batches)
4. Monitoring the Batch Status
5. Retrieving any Batch Results

I covered this (with respect to Bulk API updates) in [Choose Your Own Adventure - Dirty Dozen showdown with the REST API vs SOAP API vs BULK API](http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/01/choose-your-own-adventure-dirty-dozen.html#BulkAPI)

Answer (score 4):

The Data Loader uses one API call to log in, one to describe all objects, one when you start mapping fields or building a query, and one API call per 200 records (by default). A very light object with public sharing, no validation rules, process builders, etc, may very well end up using 30 API calls per second, but you'll end up deleting about 6,000 records per second at that point. The lighter the object, the faster your deletes are. You'll still use the same number of API calls, and the same number of records will be processed, it'll just use those same numbers of calls faster since there's less work to do.

Comment: Is the per 200 records always the case or is it changed based on batch size?

Comment: what about using bulk API option where 10k records can be processed by a single batch?

Comment: @LanceShi 200 is the default. You can change the batch size from 1 to 2000; it always counts as 1 API call per batch. The default value is probably recommended unless you think you can go higher (for lighter objects), or you may need smaller batches if you encounter time outs. For SOAP, the default, one batch is one API call.

Comment: @SantanuBoral Batch may use fewer or more API calls, because of the polling required. For very light objects, it'll probably be far less than using SOAP, but for objects with lots of code and rules, bulk might be more calls. I'd say that bulk API would probably use fewer calls than SOAP on average, but one would actually want to test it and find out.